# Continue using Develop branch after successful Pull Request?

Tags: git, github, aws-codepipeline, github-desktop

I have a very basic scenario but I don't understand what is the correct way of handling it.

I have a Master Branch and a Develop Branch

Master does not receive commits directly, I make commits to develop which triggers an AWS code pipeline - these are tested approved and if ok I make a pull request

Pull request is Merged with Master (not sure if I am doing this right I use the rebase and merge option from github).

So far everything is good.

Now I want to continue doing some work so i make more commits to Develop and get ready to do a new Pull request. My problem is now it saying it will do all the commits since i originally made the Develop branch not just the ones since the Pull Request.

I could delete develop after each pull request and remake it but this makes an error in code pipeline, i'd rather just keep develop, and somehow get these inline.

I don't know what step is missing and I could really use some help, I tried looking for similar questions on here and on google but nothing really matched exactly.

If i have made a mistake on this one that's ok but moving forward i'd really appreciate knowing the correct steps to make this a smooth process.

If it matters at all i am using Github Desktop but if command line is needed that's fine.

Comment: If you want to keep your devel branch unchanged, you probably don' t want to rebase before merging. If there are no changes on master, a fast-forward merge should work

Comment: Thanks @perivesta does the fast-forward merge tell the develop branch that the master now includes its commits to start working clean? Or would there still be a step to get develop to understand this?

Comment: The whole story is complicated, but the gist of it is: A rebase changes the commits on the devel branch (server-side) and so you get a mismatch when you try to continue using your local copy. A fast-forward doesn't do that.

Comment: `the develop branch that the master now includes its commits` The devel branch knows nothing about master, that concept does not exist in git. If you don't understand what merging and rebasing do exactly, letting the server automatically do it may be confusing. Maybe you'll want to [look at this](https://learngitbranching.js.org)

Comment: I have tried with not doing the rebase in github and it works perfect. I will learn about fast forwarded merge as well to understand more as i have not looked at that yet in my learning.

I believe when i said tell the develop branch... i should have said that because now the master branch has the same commits (same hashes) then when the PR happens those commits would not be included in the PR as they are already in master.

Comment: Do you have other developers sharing `develop`? Also, what do you mean by remaking the `develop` branch after a completed PR "makes an error in code pipeline"?

Comment: The error happens in pipeline because the branch has been deleted so the pipeline tries to run but fails with a message similar to branch not found. (in the source step of the pipeline)

I am the only developer at this stage - would the solution change if there was another developer?

Comment: OK. I think I have enough info to provide a useful answer. (Yes, the solution might change if you have mutliple devs...see my answer below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this:

> `master` does not receive commits directly, I make commits to `develop` which triggers an AWS code pipeline - these are tested approved and if ok I make a pull request

I'm going to start by focusing on the words: "these are tested approved **and if ok**..."

This suggests if the tests fail, that you will fixup `develop` and push out your changes to see if your fix attempt worked. Given this, `develop` is not necessarily a "good" branch in the same way that `master` is a "good" branch. Instead you're treating `develop` kind of like a "feature" or "topic" branch that is a work-in-progress until you get it right. Given that, I like your suggestion of resetting `develop` periodically, and if you're the only user of the `develop` branch at the moment, then resetting after every PR into `master` makes sense. Regarding the issue of your pipeline breaking:

> I could delete develop after each pull request and remake it but this makes an error in code pipeline

And clarified in your comment:

> The error happens in pipeline because the branch has been deleted so the pipeline tries to run but fails with a message similar to branch not found.

The simple solution for this is to never actually delete the `develop` branch. Instead just reset it, perhaps like this:

```
git fetch
git switch develop
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force
```

In this way the branch will always exist and the pipeline won't complain about not being able to find the branch.

**Branch name tip:** Although branch names don't actually matter as long as you (and your team if you have one) understand exactly what they are and how they work, I would consider renaming your `develop` branch to something else. The branch name `develop` is oftentimes associated with a workflow called [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), and in that context the `develop` branch lives forever and normally would never get reset. Typically testing would be done on feature branches until they are ready, and then they are merged into `develop` with the goal of always having it be in a "good" state. The workflow you are currently using is more akin to [GitHub Flow](https://githubflow.github.io/). In that flow you branch off of `master` with a relevant named feature branch (e.g. `user/b2020/add-new-cool-thing` or `feature/add-new-cool-thing`), and then merge it into `master` when you're done and delete that branch. Note you may have multiple feature branches going at once, especially if you add more team members. Most testing pipelines will enable you to test multiple branch names, (e.g. `feature/*` or `user/*`, etc.), but if you want to lock down to a specific branch name, I would suggest calling it `next`, which is what the maintainers of Git call their short-lived test branch in [gitworkflow](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows). If you have multiple developers each of you would still make feature branches off of `master`, but first merge them into `next` for testing before you complete your merge into `master`. Then periodically reset `next` whenever it makes sense. You could do it after every PR if you wish; at my company we currently do it every Monday morning. For now, if you like working on only one branch, consider renaming your `develop` branch to `next`, and you can commit to that directly until you have other team members, or until you decide to work on multiple features in parallel. And while you're renaming branches, you could rename `master` to `main` too if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had a terrible misunderstanding of rebase when doing the PR which was causing my main issue of the subsequent PRs to have other commits in them. Your answer has also helped me understand about resetting (which is what i think i was also missing) can I clarify one more thing with you please.

Which would be the better technique between doing a Merge when accepting the PR (not squash or rebase) vs the reset approach which i suppose could have rebase / squash. If doing the Merge is there a reason to reset?

Would one be cleaner than the other and if so why?

Comment: Actually I do have another follow up I have been going over the lean git branching which was recommended, and i now wonder would git branch -f develop master work and what if anything the difference between that and the git reset option would be? And would there be a preference and why?

Comment: When learning Git, rebase is arguably one of the most difficult concepts to fully grasp initially. I'd recommend reading up about rebase from multiple sources until you feel that you nailed it. The short of it is, think of "rebase" as "rewriting" commits. When you rewrite a commit you typically change something about that commit (maybe just the parent commit), and this will change the commit ID. When you rebase onto another branch, you are changing the branch you currently have checked out by rewriting some commits. cont...

Comment: By default, rebase will rewrite *all* commits whose commit ID's are not on the target branch. You can do a fancy rebase using the `--onto` option, which enables you to select a specific range of commits to rewrite, if you wish to do something other than the default.

Comment: My personal preference is to fixup my personal feature branches to make them perfect before completing a PR into long-lived shared branch such as `master`. This means I'll amend my commits, possibly squash some, and also rebase my branch onto the latest `origin/master` before completing the PR. Which PR completion merge type you select is a matter of taste. If you don't feel you have valuable information contained in multiple commits, you can choose a squash merge. (If you always have just one commit then squash wouldn't hurt anything.) I personally like having multiple commits so I don't.

Comment: My personal preference is something GitHub doesn't have yet, which is a semi-linear merge. This is similar to the "rebase, merge" option but it uses `--no-ff` to force a merge commit. When using GitHub I rebase my branch myself and then use regular merge and if I do it fast enough I can accomplish the same thing. The reason I prefer the merge commit is so I can see all the commits brought in by a single PR as a group. Note that whatever merge type you choose, the *state* of your code should be identical; the differences should only affect what the resulting graph looks like.

Comment: Regarding `reset`, note that isn't relevant to PR completion strategies. As for resetting `develop` to `master` after completing your PR, you are correct that there is no difference between `git branch -f develop master` and `git switch develop` (to checkout `develop`) followed by `git reset --hard master`. Note, I would recommend using `origin/master` in those commands instead of your local copy of `master`, because this way once you `git fetch` your `origin/*` branches will be up to date, and you don't need to update your local copy of `master`. (I might even delete local `master`!)